# How do i provide application instance in a module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-room, dagger

I'm not able to build my app due to following error.

> @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components

I'm using

`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0"`

`kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0"`

My apps RoomModul looks like this:

```
@Module
class RoomModule(application: Application) {

@Singleton
private var logDatabase : LogDatabase =
    Room.databaseBuilder(application, LogDatabase::class.java, "log-db").build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesLogDatabase() : LogDatabase {
    return logDatabase
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesLogDao() : LogDao {
    return logDatabase.getLogDao()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesLogRepository(logDao: LogDao) : LogRepository {
    return LogDataSource(logDao)
}
}
```

And my AppComponent looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    MainActivityModule::class,
    RoomModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
}

fun inject(logApplication: LogApplication)
}
```

So my RoomModule needs the application to provide the room database. But I keep getting the error.

I thought that @BindsInstance should provide the application instance to my modules. I also tried to remove the constructor from my RoomModule with no success. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use this
@Module
class RoomModule()
{
 @Singleton
 @Provides
 private var logDatabase(application: Application) : LogDatabase =
 Room.databaseBuilder(application, LogDatabase::class.java, "log-db").build()
----
}

And Remove this line ---> fun inject(logApplication: LogApplication)
from AppComponent
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this. At the moment i managed to get it done by adding `fun roomModule(roomModule: RoomModule): Builder` to my Builder and add `.roomModule(RoomModule(application))` on building appComponent. But this feels wrong and i think this shouldnt be the way how to do it.